# PhpStorm metadata file for repository classes

Tags: php, phpstorm

In our application, we use repositories for models that are fetched from the database. So, we have an abstract repository that knows about the database, has a `loadById` method to load a database record and an abstract `getEntity` method that creates an object for that specific repository. Example code:

```
abstract class EntityRepository {
  /**
   * @param int $id
   * @return AbstractEntity
   */
  public function loadById($id) {
    $record = $this->db->loadById($id);
    $entity = $this->getEntity();
    return $this->inflate($record, $entity);
  }

  /**
   * @return AbstractEntity
   */
  protected abstract function getEntity();
}

class PeopleRepository extends EntityRepository {
  protected function getEntity() {
    return new PeopleEntity();
  }
}

abstract class AbstractEntity {
  private $id;

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $id;
   */
  public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }
}

class PeopleEntity extends AbstractEntity {
  private $name;

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }

  /**
   * @param string $name;
   */
  public function setName($name) {
    $this->name= $name;
  }
}
```

When using an instance of `PeopleRepository` and fetching a model through `loadById`, PhpStorm is not able to resolve the returned model to a concrete type, but provides only code completion for the functions of `AbstractEntity`. Is there any simple way to make it work?

In https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata, I've only found ways to make it work for concrete classes and their functions. So, enumerating all repository classes and all their ways of creating an entity might work. But I'd love to see an abstract way of defining like "All instances of EntityRepository will return an entity of that type defined in `getEntity()` when loading an entity"

Comment: I'm not super sure that I got all this right (too complicated for me to grasp it without rather full code sample) .. but why not describe the correct return type for `loadById()` in `PeopleRepository`? Sort of re-declare it via `@method` PHPDoc tag. I believe this would be more correct way here .. as Metadata way is about correct return type based on the parameter value.

Comment: @LazyOne there is no need to override `loadById` in all extending repositories - that's what an abstract class is used for ;) After all, I strongly simplified the methods to not make the code even longer. The methods in the abstract repository might be numerous and longer

Comment: You are NOT overriding it. Actual method (code) is **untouched**. It's about providing correct return type. **Simple one line in PHPDoc** comment for the class -- that's it.

Comment: Okay, I've tried it, and basically it works - up to the point where you try to jump to the declaration of `loadById`. It points to the annotation instead of the actual implementation :(

Comment: And that's expected. I doubt that you really need to jump to that actual method. But If you still need it -- invoke `Navigate | File Structure` afterwards and it will list all methods for current class and parent (or some another way that might be more suitable for you).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a blanket way of doing this. Even using PHPStorm meta you have to be explicit for each case. Perhaps the way of doing this is by doing something like adding a repository facade e.g.

```
class RepositoryFacade {
     public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
          if ($args[0] == People::class) {
              array_shift($args);
              return new PeopleRepository()->{$method}(...$args); 
          }
     }
}
```

Then you might be able to typehint this using:

```
override(RepositoryFacade::loadById(0), type(0));
```

Of course the facade is not really the best pattern to be using in general so I can see how this might not be ideal.

Comment: But if I do this, I'd have to cover all possible entity classes in the facade? Adding a new entity repository leads to editing the facade? Then I'd rather add such new repository class to the meta file manually

Comment: I didn't want to judge! If I had a solution already, I haven't posted my question ;) And if this is not possible in an abstract way after all, I'm happy to take the best of all non-good solutions ;)